# Copy a file in Nautilus and use it in a shell command line

Tags: command-line, x11, nautilus, clipboard

Suppose I click on a file in Nautilus. How can I copy the full address to the clipboard, and then easily paste it into a shell command that I'm typing in a terminal?

Comment: Yes, press Ctrl+C to copy, which you already know… What's the question here?

Comment: I'm not looking to copy the file, I'm looking to copy the address of the file.

Comment: And when you paste in a terminal, you get the address of the file.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this.  But trying it out, it doesn't seem to paste in a terminal ready format (i.e., if there are spaces in the file names or what not).

Comment: What do you mean by “terminal ready format”? Do you mean that you want the file name quoted for shell use (e.g. `'/home/george/some thing.txt'`), and not the file name (like `/home/george/some thing.txt`)? You should write what you mean in your question, we can't read your mind.

Comment: It does paste, I just tried it.  You must remove the `file://` protocol. (In Dolphin/KDE)

Comment: Gilles -- yes, that's what I meant (I should have been more clear). I'd like to be able, for example, to copy the full path of the file and then open a terminal to quickly open it in a different program using a paste.

Comment: @George - FWIW, you can just drag&drop the file/folder from Nautilus in Gnome terminal and the full path will be copied & quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy. When you paste into a terminal, what you'll get is the file name (with its full path).

You get the raw file name, which won't be directly usable in a shell command if it contains spaces or other special characters. To use the file name in a command, don't use a paste command from the terminal, let the shell do the pasting. Install the program [`xsel`](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) (packaged in most distributions) and call it on your command line, inside a [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution). You need double quotes around the command substitution to protect special characters such as spaces.

```
$ ls -l "`xsel -b`"
```

Answer (score 1):

Click on it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and just paste it. If you use `xclip -selection c w` for pasting instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> you won't get any `file://` prefix or URL encoding.

I recommend wrapping that into something more convenient to use and using it for manipulating the clipboard when you're in the terminal. Here's an article that discusses this method using the commandline tool `vipe`, it's titled: [`VIPE` WITHOUT MOREUTILS](http://pskocik-tech.blogspot.cz/2014/10/vipe-without-moreutils-vipe-is-really.html).